# Correct reverse proxy to aws-es-proxy instance?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, proxy, elasticsearch, kibana

I installed a VPC with an Elasticsearch cluster with kibana on AWS.

As that is VPC, it is not accessible publicly.
Thus, to be able to access the kibana interface, I installed the https://github.com/abutaha/aws-es-proxy `aws-es-proxy`.

So far so good. I can access the logs at :9200.

However, to share with my colleagues, I wanted to set up https and a DNS.

If I run nginx like this:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9200/
    }
```

then this just forwards the request there, and I get the root elasticsearch response.

Kibana is actually at `http://localhost:9200/_plugin/kibana/app/kibana`. Therefore, to share with my colleagues it's `https://my.domain.name/_plugin/kibana/app/kibana`.

`aws-es-proxy` documentation in fact says:

> To access Kibana, use http://localhost:9200/_plugin/kibana/app/kibana

I wanted to setup a redirection so that `https://my.domain.name` would just forward directly to kibana.

I have tried many combinations, the latest being:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9200/_plugin/kibana/app/kibana;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:9200/_plugin/kibana/app/kibana https://my.domain.name/;
}
```

But when I go to `https://my.domain.name` I now get an empty screen.
The console has a number of 404 like this:

`GET https://my.domain.name/_plugin/kibana/bundles/app/kibana/bootstrap.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

How can I get this correctly to work?